# Did I set the equal symbols correctly here (picture inside)?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have asked so many people before and everyone has said different things to me.
One said it's not correct / alright because I have used double-equal symbols (see the ones on the very right side of the paper) while the other ones said I need to do a new line for every equal symbol (this would waste so much space!), or I need equivalence symbols at some points... Very confusing and there were more different opinions, too.

Now I'd like to know from you, what do you think about that. If you were my teacher, would you give me minus points here, in the exam? (I have already asked my professor but she hasn't replied yet.)

How would you recommend solving this problem without wasting too much space / writing too much?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you should only have equals signs at the beginning of the row. You basically wrote down two equals signs in sequence.

Comment: I wouldn't give you minus points on the exam, of course. It's like missing a comma in a sentence - mathematically irrelevant.

Comment: I've seen many mathematics books and articles write with "double" equals signs as you have here. It should definitely not give you negative scores, the meaning is crystal clear. That said, if forced to do only one equals sign, I'd put it on the next row, not as the last symbol of the current row.